# How to setup AutoScaling Docker Hosts in Azure Container Service

Tags: azure, autoscaling, azure-container-service, azure-vm-scale-set

I want to configure ScaleSets / AutoScaling for Master and Agent Virtual Machines in Azure Container Service for High Availability and Fault Tolerance.
Is it automatically taken care by Azure or we need to configure it manually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could configure autoscaling for Agent VMs in Azure Container Service.  After deploying Azure Container service it creates a Virtual Machines Scale Set for agent VMs. We can enable autoscaling and add scaling rules in it. Thanks